# How to correlate dynamic boundary in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

If we are having dynamic left and right boundary in response, then **how to correlate them in Jmeter?**

I found few useful article to correlate in Loadrunner, by using text flag in web_reg_save_param like "/DIG", "/BIN", "/ALNUM", "/IG". Or we can do that using web_reg_save_param_regexp.

Comment: could you be more specific and show us some example please?

Comment: If we are getting response like below for each

Comment: Your question is vague and confusing as you are referencing Loadrunner functions. Please provide clear examples on what you (want to) do/did in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

In Jmeter you use the relevant Regular expression in `Regular Expression Extractor` added as a post processor of the request.

for example for LoadRunner correlation:

> Source: “GraphA123567EndGraphA”
>
> Solution:
>   web_reg_save_param_regexp(“ParamName=CorrValue”,
>   “RegExp=\“Graph[A-Za-z]\”, \“([0-9]+)\”, \“EndGraph[A-Za-z]\””, LAST);
>
> Result: 123567

You will use [Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/13):

```
Graph([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)EndGraph([A-Za-z]+)
```

with Template: `$2$` to get relevant group and in Jmeter ParamName is Reference Name

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't operate "boundaries", the most popular Post Processor is [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) which can handle both static or dynamic "boundaries" which you can set using Perl5-style regular expressions.

For example if you want to extract numeric value between `foo` and `bar` the relevant JMeter regular expression would be `foo(\d+)bar`

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Number]

If you are looking for a mix of numbers and letters you can use `foo(\w+)bar`

[image: JMeter extract alphanumeric]

The same approach you can follow if your response data is like `foo1_A_VERY_INTERESTING_STRING_bar2` where `1` and `2` are dynamic:

[image: JMeter Dynamic Variables]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)